# Método de subtrair dois valores da soma dos registros vindos do banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde a todos, estou criando uma classe que funcionará como caixa

onde o mesmo somará todos os registros encontrados no banco com a coluna no valor de ENTRADA e SAÍDA e no fim eu subtraio Entrada - Saída mas não está dando certo alguem pode me dizer onde eu possa estar errando?

Função da classe Lancamento

```
public function getSaldo(){

    $conexao = new Conexao();

    $sql1 = "SELECT SUM(valor) FROM $this->table WHERE tipo = Entrada";
    $sql2 = "SELECT SUM(valor) FROM $this->table WHERE tipo = Saida";

    $entrada = $conexao->login($sql1);

    $saida = $conexao->login($sql2);

    $saldo = $entrada[0] - $saida[0];

    return $saldo;


}
```

Função Login

```
public function login($rawQuery, $params = array()):array
{

    $stmt = $this->query($rawQuery, $params);

    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Página de testes da função

```
<?php

require_once "../Controllers/Config.php";

$lancamento = new Lancamento;

$lancamento->getSaldo();


?>
```

A classe login estou usando temporáriamente pretendo implementar uma função específica para este caso, desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda

Comment: Não seria isso: `$saldo = $entrada[0]["SUM(valor)"] - $saida[0]["SUM(valor)"];`? Retorna algum erro? Se sim, qual?

Comment: Olá Roberto coloquei como voce falou e deu o erro abaixo

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PC\gentelella-master\production\Class\Lancamento.php on line 96

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PC\gentelella-master\production\Class\Lancamento.php on line 96

Comment: Seu erro está nos dois `SELECT`, texto deve estar entre `'` (aspas simples).
`$sql1 = "SELECT SUM(valor) FROM $this->table WHERE tipo = 'Entrada'";
    $sql2 = "SELECT SUM(valor) FROM $this->table WHERE tipo = 'Saida'";`

Comment: infelizmente o erro persiste

Notice: Undefined index: SUM(valor) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PC\gentelella-master\production\Class\Lancamento.php on line 96

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PC\gentelella-master\production\Class\Lancamento.php on line 96

Comment: No lugar de `$this->table` você tem que colocar o nome da sua tabela.

Comment: Esse erro que você esta me informando, quer dizer que não existe o item 0 no array `$entrada`. Isso significa que seu `SELECT` não esta retornando nada ou está errado.

Comment: Roberto, só pra você entender na classe existe o atributo table = "Lancamentos" que dentro deste atributo está contido o nome da tabela entende? engraçado que é exatamente isto, não estou percebendo onde estou errando nesse select

Comment: Deu certo Roberto obrigado pela força man